# Generating a Scaffold application

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails, node.js, scaffolding

How do you go about creating a tool like Yeoman or Gulp? Not to compete but for educational purposes, how would you go about building a tool to scaffold the skeleton of an application?

Could you point me into some resources for generating such tool or any resource that would be helpful in teaching me the foundation for generating something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own scaffold generator before and generally how I think it is done is that you need a few things

1. Skeleton templates for views, controllers and models (if that is the kind of thing you are generating)
2. Database writing scripts to change relevant databases (if required, like you want to generate some empty model tables)

Generally you would write up the skeleton templates, and you can do this in whatever format you think is best. What I did when I wrote my scaffolding was to replace certain strings with the variable the user would enter. Sometimes I had to inflect that variable (change from singular to plural and such). in the template to get things going.

As simple as it is I'm sure there are smarter ways to generate scaffolds. I mean I'm sure the tools you have listed are open source since yeomen is associated with node (haven't used it but did a google search). Perhaps just take a gander at yeomen's source code to see how they did it right? 
They actually have a tutorial right on their website detailing creating your own generator: http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html

Enjoy and good luck sir.